# Laravel Livewire : Basic Pagination not working, with livewire 2.5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Phrase Livewire component

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Phrases;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Phrase extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $phrases;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.phrase', [
            'phrases' => Phrases::paginate(10),
        ]);
    }

    public function mount()
    {
    }
}
```

And I also have its balde component where I trying to iterate and paginate them.

```php
<div class="w-2/3">
    <h2>List of Phrases</h2>
    <div>
        @foreach($phrases as $phrase)
            <p>{{ $phrase->word }}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    {{ $phrases->links() }}
</div>
```

The error that I am getting is

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\wp-local\upwork-tool\resources\views\livewire\phrase.blade.php)
```

When I dump the variable it returns null.

But the same value when `dd()` in component render method it gives proper data.

```php
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#1239 ▼
  #total: 60
  #lastPage: 6
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1509 ▶}
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
```

Using

```
"livewire/livewire": "^2.5"
```

Comment: I think it's using `public $phrases` instead of the variable being passed in [`'phrases' => ...]`. Did you try `$this->phrases = Phrases::paginate(10);`, then `return view('livewire.phrase');`?

Comment: It can be many things. Maybe you're calling the blade file from somewhere else, maybe there is a typo that is not cleart with what you posted or maybe the `public $phrases` is interfering. try to `dump()` (without die()) from the blade file to get more certainty.

Comment: @TimLewis When I do that I get, `Livewire component's [phrase] public property [phrases] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.`

Comment: @N69S, I have confirmed that the blade file the is the correct blade file as other livewire functions are working. I have double checked for variable names.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You won't be able to use Pagination if you go with any of those datatypes (array would work with `@foreach()`, but then `$phrases->links` would fail). Can you make it `protected` and see if that works? Or maybe just remove `public $phrases;` and go with what you had before `return view('livewire.phrase', ['phrases' => Phrases::paginate(10)]);` Sidenote, haven't used Livewire before, so this is simply at what it's trying to do.

Comment: Losing `public $phrases` did the trick. Any idea why would this be the issue ? Seems very strange.

Comment: I guess the way Livewire handles variables being sent to the view. Since you defined `public $phrases;`, and `['phrases' => ...]`, only one of those can be used, and it defaulted to `public $phrases;` which would be `null`. I would have expected the 2nd definition to override the first, but whatever is happening behind the scenes is the opposite of that.